# What does it mean if the column “column” is NULL when running the sp_depends system proc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running the proc 'sp_depends' to find dependencies of tables and columns from a proc, however i am getting a few values where the column name in the results table is NULL.

Does anyone know what this means?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `IS NULL` means that column may have received blank values. In `SQL` blank values are called `NULL`. Note : ' ' is not null equals to `NULL`. In fact `NULL` is not equal to anyone. You would have to use special operator `IS NOT NULL` & `IS NULL` for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the objects returned in the `sp_depends` result set just have no any column. For example, a procedure. A procedure referenced  by this result set will have `NULL` at `column` column.

Answer (score 0):

They are objects that depend on no column.

Not sure if you're aware, so. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-depends-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> This feature is in maintenance mode and may be removed in a future
>   version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new
>   development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use
>   this feature. Use sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities and
>   sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities instead.